# How to delete a FAILED VPC Peering Connection Creation?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cli, amazon-vpc

**How to delete a FAILED VPC Peering Connection Creation?**

While creating a VPC peering connection, I gave an invalid VPC id and the peering connection creation failed. Later I corrected the VPC id and could create the peering connection. Now I am trying to delete the failed peering connection, but the option is greyed out in AWS dashboard.

[image]

CLI is not letting me to delete it. How do I delete a failed VPC peering connection?

```
$ aws ec2 delete-vpc-peering-connection --vpc-peering-connection-id pcx-xxxxxxxx

An error occurred (InvalidStateTransition) when calling the DeleteVpcPeeringConnection operation: Invalid state transition for pcx-xxxxxxxx, attempted to transition from failed to deleting
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Looks like the FAILED peering connection will remain for 2 days for the requestor and 2 hours for the acceptor.

See: [VPC Peering Connection Lifecycle](http://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/AmazonVPC/latest/PeeringGuide/vpc-peering-basics.html#vpc-peering-lifecycle)

> **Rejected**: The owner of the accepter VPC has rejected a pending-acceptance VPC peering connection request. During this state,
>   the request cannot be accepted. The **rejected VPC peering connection
>   remains visible to the owner of the requester VPC for 2 days, and
>   visible to the owner of the accepter VPC for 2 hours**. If the request
>   was created within the same AWS account, the rejected request remains
>   visible for 2 hours.

Comment: The description here is for `Rejected` not `Failed` but the answer for `Failed` seems to be 2 hours for both sides.